# C# Copy file from Android to PC

Tags: c#, android, file, copy

I need to copy a bunch of files from an Android phone to the PC.
It doesn't work the normal way, the PC is super slow and crashes all the time for some reason.
I want to copy it file by file.

My problem is that if I use Directory.GetFiles("Path") or DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("Path") it does add the persistant Datapath to the path for some reason and I get this error message:

DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\GameDev\CopyProgram\Dieser PC\HTC One M9\Interner gemeinsamer Speicher'.

The actual path is only "Dieser PC\HTC One M9\Interner gemeinsamer Speicher", is there any way to do that?

```
//there is an input field where you can enter the paths
(copy it from the explorer)
[SerializeField]
private string copyFrom = "Dieser PC\HTC One M9\Interner gemeinsamer Speicher";
[SerializeField]
private string copyTo = "C:\Users\Nutzer\Desktop\Neuer Ordner";

private bool running = false;

public void Copy()
{
    if(running == true)
    {
        return;
    }

    running = true;

    //Start
    //Get all items from folder
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(copyFrom);
    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles();

    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        string currentFile = file.DirectoryName + "/" + file.Name;
        string copyFile = copyTo + "/" + file.Name;

        try
        {
            if (file == null)
                continue;

            File.Copy(currentFile, copyFile, true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    //End
    running = false;
}
```

I searched through the internet and could not find a solution, please help!

Thanks!

Comment: `The actual path is only "Dieser PC\HTC One....` That is not a path at all. Under which OS? Pretty unclear what you are doing and where. Starting with 'Directory.' what type? And how did you instantiate?

Comment: Further it is unclear where your C# code should run.

Comment: The program should run on the pc

Comment: Give better info. Put the values for copyFrom and copyTo in your post. Should we guess all. And react to all comments and answer all questions.

Comment: I did. If I copy the path from the explorer it gives me "Dieser PC\HTC One M9\Interner gemeinsamer Speicher".

Comment: It's a Windows PC.

Comment: Well you should realise that that is not a valid path. I said that before and you did not even react on it.  Your To path is correct as it starts with a Windows drive letter.

Comment: When I plug in the smartphone with an usb and click at the folders path this is what it gives me, there is now "K:\" or something like on an usb stick, I don't know why too. I tried different settings at the phone but it is always the same.

Comment: What you take as source is a relative path (that it does not exist on your PC is another story) and somehow the OS tries to make a full path of that relative path.

Comment: Wel then your from path should start with K:\.

Comment: If there is no drive letter then the MTP protocol is used. Which is normal now adays. Earlier Android deviced were mounted as drives and then you had a drive letter.

Comment: Mhm okay, do you know any workaround for that?

Comment: No. Use an MTP library (if it exists) or ask in a windows user forum how to assign a drive letter to an mtp drive. Once you know tell me.